# How to update Ruby on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Apologies in advance if this is a too nubs problem.

One friend got Beginning Rails 3 and we started playing Ruby using it (as .net developers!). I have installed Ubuntu 10.10 on VMWare Player - which apparently already had Ruby 1.9.2. Based on instructions in the book (with some quirks for total linux nubs) we managed to install Ruby 1.9.1 (ruby --version -> ruby 1.9.1p376 (2009-12-07 revision 26041) [i686-linux]).

But Rails (latest version - 3.0.2 I think) insist that Ruby 1.9.2 is better for our health!

So: How to update Ruby on Ubuntu 10.10? I want just this one ruby be there.

Comment: you should probably use serverfault.com instead of stackoverflow

Comment: I have the same book.  Follow the instructions on page 20, but  use ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-rc2.zip to install instead of the 1.9.1  Also consider RVM - http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: I recommend we move this to the Ubuntu site. It would help a lot more people there than here.

Comment: @Amir You are right. Thanks; My mind was focused on Ruby (programming...). How should I do that migration to serverfault?

Comment: @Levi Thanks; Please look at my comment to Amir. That stands for moving this to ubuntu forums too.

Comment: This sort of question is asked here all the time. Ultimately it might fit on serverfault better, but you're definitely NOT the first one to ask it here, and I doubt you'll be the last.

Comment: @Greg How can I move this to another exchange site? Is there a "move to X" feature? Or should delete this and ask it again?

Comment: @Amir @Greg I still think (as a .net developer) this question is at the right place. As a developer I am asking how to install a developing environment. It's like how to install F# on Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Well I guess no one else has complained about it. So keep it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [Ruby Version Manager](http://rvm.io/).

Install (yes, it takes a leap of faith):

```
$ curl https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

then

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
$ rvm use 1.9.2
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas! I just want to be sure: your second line ($ rvm use 1.9.2) makes Ruby 1.9.2 the default; is it so?

Comment: rvm use does not imply that 1.9.2 is the default, just that you want to use 1.9.2 right now. To set a default, call `rvm --default use 1.9.2`

Comment: Of course I failed to install rvm and my ubuntu is messed up with a lot of I don't know what things downloaded in various directories (based on various blogs and tutorials) and I do not like that. Maybe it's just better for my kind to ignore ubuntu and stick with windows - mine: a vista monster. Things are hard to do in ubunto (or call me nuts)! Thanks!

Comment: In what way did the rvm install fail? Time for a `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I entered at terminal: $ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head ) (recommended from their site) and at some point progress stops at 17% (I have repeated that and every time same thing happens).

Comment: Wayne has been known to be very active and helpful over at #rvm on irc.freenode.net http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm you could always describe your problem there.

Comment: Yes, Wayne is very responsive. RVM is very solid, but when I used to get myself hosed up and he'd have a fix immediately. Once you're up and running with it do `rvm get head` often, at least weekly, because he updates it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to manage Ruby versions is through RVM: http://rvm.io/

Rails is right about the Ruby versions, btw.